# $\mathsf{GCH}$ in $L[U]$ without the Rowbottom property

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

For $\kappa$ a measurable, and $U$ is (normal) measure, we know that $L[U]\models\mathsf{GCH}$.  That $\mathsf{GCH}$ holds above $\kappa$ is easy: what I'm interested in is $\mathsf{GCH}$ below $\kappa$.  Most of the regular proofs of this fact resort properties of Rowbottom cardinals.  I've been told it can be done with the comparison method/process, but I'm not sure how this argument would go.

My intuition would be to proceed as in $L$: for $x\subseteq\lambda<\kappa$, take a skolem hull and get some $L_\alpha[W]$, and then iterate until things match up, and then argue somehow about the relation between $U$ and the resulting embedded ultrafilter $W_\gamma$. The end goal would be that we get $x$ in some $L_\beta[U]$ for $\beta<\lambda^+$, but it's not obvious to me how to show this if this is even the right route to take.

Any reference or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You can find this proof for example in §20 in Kanamoris book (its shown there first via the Rowbottom property, later with an approach similar to what you describe). Note that there are some subsets of $\omega$ in $L[U]$ that are not even in $L_\kappa[U]$, so your end goal is not achievable.